# How to programmatically determine the URL of a Wikipedia article for a list of episodes of any television show

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia

I'm writing a script to rename files based off of the information found on the "list of X episodes" Wikipedia pages where X is the name of a TV show. Ex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MythBusters_episodes. I'm using the Wikipedia API to scrape the data from the articles.

I want the script to handle any available TV show, but I don't know how to determine if there is a Wikipedia article for that show or not. Given the title of the show that you want to search for, what is the best way to determine if an article with lists of episodes exists and if it does, return the URL? I think the best way would probably be to crawl through Wikipedia somehow and develop a database / dictionary / hashmap linking shows to their respective article URLs, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do such a thing.

I can't simply guess what the URL is because, for example, the Office has an article for the U.S. version and a separate article for the U.K. version, and sometimes the URL of the article does not follow the standard format, like Doctor Who which uses the word serials rather than episodes.

Currently, to test a few basic shows, I've got a hardcoded dictionary:

```
shows = {"The Office" : "List_of_The_Office_(U.S._TV_series)_episodes", \
         "Breaking Bad" : "List_of_Breaking_Bad_episodes", \
         "Community" : "List_of_Community_episodes", \
         "Parks and Recreation" : "List_of_Parks_and_Recreation_episodes", \
         "Game of Thrones" : "List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes", \
         "Doctor Who (2005+)" : "List_of_Doctor_Who_serials", \
         "Adventure Time" : "List_of_Adventure_Time_episodes", \
         "Suits" : "List_of_Suits_episodes"}
```

Obviously I don't want to hardcode this for every possible show available. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: A hacky approach would be to search Google for "list of {show} episodes" and use the first result.

Comment: While Wikipedia does have standards for these things, the standards (a) have exceptions and (b) change over time. So there is no way to do this except heuristically. You can do something quick&dirty—you've found some patterns that together probably will match 90% of the time if you just try each pattern until one succeeds. Or you can try to come up with a complex set of rules to feed into an inference engine. Or you can train a neural net. Or… whatever. But there's no way to do anything better.

Comment: Also, it sounds like the problem you're trying to solve is ambiguous in the first place. "The Office has an article for the U.S. version and a separate article for the U.K. version." So, when you want a list of episodes for The Office, which one of the two do you want?

Comment: @Blender I thought of that, but in looking up how to do that I saw that you need to have access to the Google API, which restricts how many searches you can do. If I ever wanted to release this script would anyone be able to use it or would it that be a limiting factor?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, determining if you want the U.S. version or a different version is another problem, but I figure that can be solved by having multiple results for the show "The Office" in the dictionary, then asking for clarification from the user about which URL they want.

Comment: @NSchrading: So, how are you going to programmatically determine that "The Office (U.S. version)" and "The Office (U.K. version)" belong in the same show entry "The Office"? And it's more complicated than you think, too. Consider "Battlestar Galactica (2004 TV series)" vs. "Battlestar Galactica (1978, 1980)", or "Primeval" vs. "Primeval: New World". Again, the only answer is to do it heuristically (or manually)—it's exactly the same problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: One last point: Doctor Who doesn't follow the "standard format" because the standard is more complicated than you think. The classic Doctor Who series originally didn't have names for individual episodes, but only for serials of usually around 4-6 episodes. Later, they began having names for both, but the serial was still a more reasonable "main unit" for the show than the episode. Only in the revived series did it become more about individual episodes (and even there, consider "The End of Time"). (Classic) Doctor Who is not the only show that works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `List of Show Name episodes` is your best bet. [In the case of Doctor Who](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_episodes), that page is a redirect to the correct name. [In the case of The Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Office_episodes), it's a redirect to a disambiguation page.

Comment: I hadn't tested if there were redirects or disambiguation pages. Thanks for pointing that out. I bet just using that format as an initial guess could work.